# Can i find out point of user click on a button?

Tags: android

Suppose I have a button of height and width 120 dp on a layout. Is it possible to get the position where the user clicks this button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
 button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getRawX();
            float y = event.getRawY();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity onCreate code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    // this is the view on which you will listen for touch events
    final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
            String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" +                         
            String.valueOf(event.getY()));
            return true;
           }
       });
}
```

layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                      
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/touchView" 
android:background="#f00" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/textView" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Hello World, TestActivity"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```